# MutationObserver in AngularJS to know when a SPA template has been loaded

Tags: angularjs, mutation-observers

I'm using MutationObserver in an AngularJS SPA to detect changes in the DOM everytime the ng-view is updated via user navigation. This is better explained here http://www.soasta.com/blog/angularjs-real-user-monitoring-single-page-applications/

This is the function which is fired with every soft navigation (within the SPA)

```
function initMutationObserver() {

    if (window.MutationObserver) {  

        // select the target node
        var target = document.querySelector('.sport');

        // create an observer instance
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {      
                console.info(mutation.type);
            });    
            console.info('**** DOM changes ****')
        });

        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true};

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(target, config);
    }
};
```

That is, everytime the user navigates to a new page within the SPA this observer detects changes in the DOM.

Problem is, for every navigation this observer gets fired many times and not only one, so I don´t really know when this is over. Has anyone any idea on how to do that? Is there a way with the MutationObserver that I can be sure the DOM has alredy finish updating and I can call the loading over?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you simply use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess?

Comment: I'm already using it, but it's not enough, as the events fired don´t take into account http requests or resource downloads that the new view might need. That's why I'm using MutationObserver, every time a new navigation is detected the observer starts observing and I want to be sure that the new view is totally rendered.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

```js
$routeProvider.when('some/path',{
  resolve: {
    data1: function(){
        //do your asynch call (promise) returning your data
    },
    data2: function(){
        //do your asynch call (promise) returning your data
    },
    controller: function(data1,data2){
      //data1 and data2 will be resolved by when controller is instantiated
    }
  }
})
```

or if you want to use ui.router

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

quite similar to the previous case

Answer (score 0):

Once your mutation has occurred, you should destroy the observer:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

You may have your `NodeList` complete or something else...

Imagine it as a [camera](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationrecord) that is waiting to see when all those DOM events happen. (You may not need all of them, by the way).

But it is important to cease its activity.